# I have a Java Class that I suspect can use a ReflectionUtil here because there are too many switch/cases, any advice?

Tags: java

I have a chunk of code here:

```
public class ParserFactory
{
    public static ParserClass getParserClass(InputStream is, CustomMap customMap,
                                           DataHandler recordHandler, DataHandler columnHandler) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        ParserClassType ParserClassType = ParserClassType.getParserClassType(customMap.getParser());
        switch (ParserClassType)
        {
            case SPECIFIC_XML:
                return new SpecificXMLParser(is, customMap.getProperties(), recordHandler, columnHandler);
            case XML:
                return new GenericXMLParser(is, customMap.getProperties(), recordHandler, columnHandler);
            case JSON:
                return new GenericJSONParser(is, customMap.getProperties(), recordHandler, columnHandler);
            case SPECIAL:
                return new SpecialParser(is, customMap.getProperties(), recordHandler, columnHandler);
            case FW:
                return new GenericFixedWidthParser(is, customMap.getProperties(), recordHandler, columnHandler);
            case CSV:
                return new GenericCSVParser(is, customMap.getProperties(), recordHandler, columnHandler);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("ParserClassType not found.");
        }
    }

    public static String getFileExtension(CustomMap customMap)
    {
        ParserClassType ParserClassType = ParserClassType.getParserClassType(customMap.getParser());
        switch (ParserClassType)
        {
            case SPECIFIC_XML: 
                return SpecificXMLParser.FILE_TYPE_OUTPUT;
            case XML:
                return GenericXMLParser.FILE_TYPE_OUTPUT;
            case JSON:
                return GenericJSONParser.FILE_TYPE_OUTPUT;
            case SPECIAL:
                return SpecialParser.FILE_TYPE_OUTPUT;
            case FW:
                return GenericFixedWidthParser.FILE_TYPE_OUTPUT;
            case CSV:
                return GenericCSVParser.FILE_TYPE_OUTPUT;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("ParserClassType not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it's not exactly too important what all these arguments are. In `getParserClass`, I retrieve an enum from `ParserClassType`. The switch handles all the possible values. A certain value will return a `ParserClass`.

The other function, `getFileExtension`, retrieves a static string from a parser class.

As my project grows, I will have many new parsers that I add. I want to make this as flexible and less-hectic as possible. I don't want to keep adding cases to this function. So.

I was looking into EnumMap. I was thinking of mapping an ENUM to a ParserClass name, so for example "XML" would make to "GenericXMLParser.class", and then I could use a ReflectionUtil to create the class with the arguments necessary or retrieve that string. Therefore, if I have to make any additions, all I need to do is add the ENUM to the enum class and make an addition to the map. But, ReflectionUtils seems to require me to provide the path of the parser. Something like "com.package.service.more.bs.SpecificXMLParser". I would rather not do that...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not using interfaces instead of reflection?

Comment: How would an interface solve my problem? They all extend from an abstract class (ParserClass); the only reason it isn't an interface is because the class also has a bunch of member variables that are shared across all the children classes. But also, in the second function, each parser has a different file output extension. Not sure how interfaces would help here... shed some light?

Comment: For example the `IParserClass` interface should provide a `getFileExtension()` method and the implementation handles this internally. Thus you don't need a switch to determine it from concrete parser implementations. But without seeing more context of your code, it's impossible to give advice how to improve it in this direction.

Comment: I see what you're saying. The specific function you're talking about in this class I shared needs to be called _before_ I have a Parser Instance. You can trust me on that. Otherwise, of course, I would totally agree with you and would have done that readily.

Comment: I recently faced this problem where I was returning various class objects based on the type. I will have a lot of types and switch case approach was not scalable for me. To solve this problem I used mapBinder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871631/gof-standard-factory-pattern-using-guice

Comment: @JohnLexus You might be interested in looking at the [_Abstract Factory_ design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) and shift the knowledge about the concrete file extensions and corresponding parser class types there.

Comment: For the context vote closer(s), there is plenty of context to review, this does not look like stub code.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar thank you for your comment; this looks like it has a serious dependency? Guice? Would rather not add a heavy dependency for something like this...

Comment: @JohnLexus  In our project, we have multiple uses of guice, so for me, the solution  I proposed was good. I agree with your point. It doesn't make sense to add this dependency just for this use case.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB please suggest a title name :)

Answer (score 3):

The only problem I see with this code is, that for extending the enum, you need to change *two* methods in the code, which spreads out changes instead of keeping them local to a single place.

You could however harness the power of the java enum (which can have fields and methods) to make the changes locally.

Something along the lines of:

```
enum ParserClassType {
    SPECIFIC_XML(SpecificXMLParser.FILE_TYPE_OUTPUT) {
        public ParserClass createParser(InputStream is, etc, ...) {
            return new SpecificXMLParser(...);
        }
    },
    XML(GenericXMLParser.FILE_TYPE_OUTPUT) {
        public ParserClass createParser(InputStream is, etc, ...) {
            return new GenericXMLParser(...);
        }
    },
    ...

    private final String fileExtension;

    private ParserClassType(String fileExtension) {
        this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
    }

    public String getFileExtension() {
        return fileExtension;
    }

    public abstract ParserClass createParser(InputStream is, etc, ...);
}

public static String getFileExtension(...) {
    ParserClassType parserClassType = ...
    return parserClassType.getFileExtension();
}

public ParserClass getParserClass(...) {
    ParserClassType parserClassType =  ...
    return parserClassType.createParser(...);
}
```

As you see, when you add a new type, you simply have to extend the enum. All the client code stays unmodified.

Apart from that, please look up the java naming conventions. Variables should start with lower case letters and definitely not shadow their class names.

Furthermore, getParserClass() / ParserClass is badly named, as it clearly involves around a concrete parser / parserInstance, not around a *class*.

Comment: Thanks for this. The classes and function names have been modified; actually, this code is nowhere to be found in the actual code. Typing out the class names would reveal more than I would like to about what I'm working on. I'll consider this, though..